# Safari does not display/render an images' css

Tags: css, image, safari

I have a profile image on my GitHub pages website that uses some css to make it look cool. The image is displayed perfectly in chrome or Firefox, but seems to ignore all css for the image in safari.

On Chrome, where the image is displayed correctly, I can see that the css rules for the image have been applied, but in safari they have not. (I hope I explained that correctly)

[This is what it looks like on chrome, as intended.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okxhI.png)

[This is what it looks like on safari, not the behaviour I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a66RF.jpg)

[This what the inspect tab looks like on safari, I do not see the css for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6msK.png)

This is the html code for the image.

```
<div id="page-welcome">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 id="main-title">
                    <a href="https://github.com/z00mm00z"><img id="profile-photo" src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/109625312?v=4"/></a>
                    Hello! I'm Robert
                </h1>
                <p>Welcome to my website.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the css for that code:

```
div#page-welcome{
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;

    a {
        float: right;
    }

    img { /* this img css is not being displaying on safari */
        width: 128px;
        height: 128px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: block;
        margin: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #ffffff;

        transition: border-radius 0.5s;
    }

    img:hover {
        border-radius: 25%;
    }
}
```

I am fairly certain the issue is that safari is not showing/using/displaying/rendering the css code for the image, but I do not know how to confirm that this is the case or how to solve it.

I have tried removing the transition and looking for styles that were not supported by safari, but could not figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: have you cleared the cache (`Ctrl` + `F5`)? PS: If you develop, you should run your browsers by default in developer mode or disable the cache by default.

Comment: @tacoshy Just tried that but doesn't seem to work - what should it have done and why?

Comment: Ok then go into the dev console and look into the network tab. Check what CSS file the browser is downloading and if it matches the file you provide. Another guess would be, that your browser does either not allow nesting yet or only nesting `id's` and `classes` but not tags in general. For that purpose you should not nest CSS and use SASS/LESS as nesting is quite "new" and not fully supported yet.

Comment: That worked! I just moved the tags out of the page-welcome id. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @tacoshy said, some browsers either do not allow nesting yet or only allow nesting id's and classes but not tags in general.

I changed this:

```css
div#page-welcome{
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;

    a {
        float: right;
    }

    img { /* this img css is not being displaying on safari */
        width: 128px;
        height: 128px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: block;
        margin: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #ffffff;

        transition: border-radius 0.5s;
    }

    img:hover {
        border-radius: 25%;
    }
}
```

To This:

```css
div#page-welcome{
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}   

div#page-welcome a {
    float: right;
}

div#page-welcome img { /* this img css is not being displaying on safari */
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #ffffff;

    transition: border-radius 0.5s;
}

div#page-welcome img:hover {
    border-radius: 25%;
}
```

(I removed the nesting)